# How do I get an RSS feed for a YouTube search result?

Tags: youtube, rss, feeds

I know how to get RSS feeds for YouTube **channels**.

I am trying to get an RSS feed for this **search result**: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=bitcoin&sp=CAI%253D

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a third party service like [this one](https://rss.app/rss-feed/create-youtube-rss-feed) unless I want to [write my own](https://www.labnol.org/code/20103-youtube-rss-feed).